# Remove BlackBerry PIMListListener

Tags: blackberry

How do i remove or clear the PIMListListeners for a BlackBerryContactList?

I added a Listener like so:

```
BlackBerryContactList contactList = (BlackBerryContactList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
contactList.addListener(new ContactsChangeListener());
```

So now when i start my app it adds another new listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably just need to reboot the device to clear them out.

To keep this from happening again, store a reference to your ContactsChangeListener, and then in your app's onClose() method add a `removeListener()` call so when the user ends your app it gets cleaned up.

Comment: I'm guessing that i have to run my app on startup an register the listener everytime the device starts

Comment: Yeah, you can just create an alternate entry point to make it easy on yourself if you don't want the full blown app launching.